# Laptop Running Slow Need to Refresh Windows 8.1 again

Tags: windows, windows-8, laptop, windows-8.1, windows-8-refresh

My laptop (Toshiba Satellite C55-A) came preinstalled with Windows 8 and I upgraded to Windows 8.1 short after. I had to refresh Windows because my brother did some creepy crap and my laptop was running slow even after antivirus cleared out issues. When the refresh happened, I didn't need any extra stuff like a disc or anything. It didn't require it.

It worked fine. I went back to Windows 8 and upgraded to 8.1 short after. It's been a while, and now I need to refresh again and Windows 8.1 is telling me that it can't find the Recovery Media. My laptop didn't come with a disc.

I found this tutorial: http://www.kapilarya.com/how-to-refresh-windows-8
that directed me to this tutorial: http://www.kapilarya.com/how-to-reset-or-refresh-windows-8-without-installation-disc

But they are based around the idea that you have a setup download from Microsoft, which I don't. How can I refresh Windows without a disc in the context of my situation?

Comment: You can't.  Something has happen to the data that this feature uses.  I believe Toshiba can provide recovery media for Windows 8.1

Comment: That's stupid...

Answer (score 0):

That's really easy! Just follow these steps:
You need Windows 8.1 installation files first and a bootable media with Windows 8.1 on it. Follow the following steps to create an installation media for Windows 8.1.

1. First Download [Windows 8.1 setup](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=271128)
2. Run the Windows 8.1 Setup program.
3. When prompted to enter a product key, enter the 25-digit product key you received when you bought Windows 8.1.
4. When prompted to install Windows 8.1, select Install by creating media, and then click Next.
5. Select the type of media you want to use: either a USB flash drive or a DVD.

To create a USB flash drive

- Click USB flash drive.
- Plug the USB flash drive into a USB port on your PC.
- When prompted, select the USB drive you want to use and then click
  Next.
- If you have files on the USB flash drive, they'll be deleted.

To create a DVD

- Click ISO file and then select the location to save the ISO file.
- Insert a blank, recordable DVD into your DVD drive.
- Burn the ISO file to the DVD using Windows Disc Image Burner, or
  another DVD burning program.

I Recommend you to save the .iso file for later use, i.e. you can have .iso file on your PC and you can burn it our make a bootable usb device later on.

After you are done with above, create a bootable USB drive, or a DVD.

Plug the media on your PC, Goto Settings > Recovery > and choose the appropriate option. And It'll work

Comment: Your answer is irrelevant to my situation. The Windows 8.1 upgrade from Windows 8 is free, which is what happened. Windows 8 came preinstalled on my system. I have already refreshed once, without the disc, but now I need to refresh again, but it is requiring a recovery media which I don't have

Comment: @user2678408 That's because the installation files you downloaded earlier before refresh have been removed from the system.
The method i just told you is to create an installation media. Create it, and Save the .ISO file (To be used for later use) and this is important.

When you create the recovery media with above process, you'll be good to go.

Comment: Well I never received a product key

Comment: It says it cannot connect to the internet